# html textbox history

Tags: php, html, caching, textbox, autocomplete

I have several textboxes in my web application.I want them to remember history when user double click on it like autocomplete operation,but they never remember.is these textboxes remembers if they are in only form field?I couldn't do that.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are remembered when they are form fields only because the users' browsers are doing that for them - it has nothing to do with your application.

But why don't you want to put the textboxes in forms? How else could you use them?

Comment: At startup you didn't - is it too late to change that? Why?